# Angular2: put field of *ngFor item as parameter into a function call

Tags: angular

I have a working management app which shows list of services running with some info (I developed it last year).
Now I need to make it display "last request" information by a click. But I got a problem. Here is a piece of code from MyManagementComponent.html file:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item of this.executorsData.executors">
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="text-center">
         [...]
          <div *ngIf="item.lastRequest != undefined">
            <div style="width:100%; align-content: right; text-align: right">
              <a onclick='$("#lastReq" + $item.id).toggle()'>last request</a>
              <div id="lastReq{{item.id}}" style="display: block; position: absolute">...placeholder for information...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see I need to pass value of **item.id** into a function call. In this case into jQuery expression but also I can create a separate function.
The problem is:

- when I use < a onclick='$("#lastReq{{item.id}}").toggle()' > it reports an error during compilation - Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
- when I use < a onclick='$("#lastReq" + $item.id").toggle()' > - I got run-time  error - MyManagementComponent.html:103 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
- when I use < a onclick='$("#lastReq" + item.id").toggle()' > - I got run-time  error - Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (transactions:1)

How to put value of **item.id** as parameter into a function call then?
In this particular case - I need "lastReq" + **item.id**.

*Note: item.id field is exists, it is displayed in 1st cell of this table (this part I omited here)*

Thank you.

PS.
Speaking of used version "@angular/core": "^6.0.3".

Comment: You use **this** on the template?

Comment: Yes. That is just a piece of code in MyManagementComponent.html file which is referenced from MyManagementComponent.ts file in traditional way: @Component({
  selector: 'app-management',
  templateUrl: './mymanagement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mymanagement.component.css']
}).

Comment: No need for the `$` here, should just be `item.id`

Comment: No, it does not work. It fail in run-time with error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (transactions:1)". Also when investigate DOM in Chrome I see that item.id is not supposed to exists at run-time(!) because item.id is only exists during template expansion. So, it is not exists at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling a click function the angle can have problems with this kind of approach. Using {{}} to compose a function name in HTML codes can cause unexpected problems (we do not know what might come in the code).

The best way to solve your problem is to create a function in your typescript by passing the ID parameter. something like that:

Include JQuery dependency in your package.json

```
dependencies: [
    ...
    "jquery": "3.3.1"
    ...
]
```

Use Jquery inside your TS code

```
import $ from "jquery";

...

export class YourComponent  {
  ...

  toggleClick(id) {
    $("#lastReq" + id).toggle();
  }
}
```

Use the new function in your HTML code:

```
<a (click)='toggleClick(item.id)'>last request</a>
```